# How do technical SEO and HTML5 markup for Headline, Section and outlines?

Tags: seo, html5, technical-seo, markup

I am looking for a good and safe example/solution for headlines in a `<section>` or `<footer>` or `<header>` markup for 2023.

I read here that by using `<main>` `<section>` etc you can also mix the headings.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#outlines
https://medium.com/alistapart/writing-html-with-accessibility-in-mind-a62026493412
(*These articles are already quite old.*)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements
(*The HTML Section Heading elements*)

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/headingsmap/flbjommegcjonpdmenkdiocclhjacmbi
(*HeadingsMap - chrome plugin*)

**My HTML5 structure should look like this:**

```html
    <body>
      <header>
        <section>
          <h3>COMPANY NAME</h3>
          <nav>META NAVIGATION</nav>
        </section>
        <nav>MAINMENU</nav>
      </header>
      <main>
        <section>SLIDER / HEADIMAGE / TEXT/IMAGE</section>
        <h1>Headline</h1>
        <p>Text / Image / UL CONTENT</p>
        (Text / Image / UL)
        <h2>Headline 2</h2>
        <p>Text</p>
        <section>
          <h3>Teaser Headline</h3>
          <p>Teaser-Text</p>
          <img>
        </section>
        <section T3-FRAME>
          <h2>Headline</h2>
          <p>Text</p>
          <img>
        </section>
        <section T3-FRAME>
          <h4>Headline</h4>
          <img>
          <p>Text</p>
        </section>
      </main>
      <footer>
       FOOTER CONTENT
       <section>
         <h4>Headline 1</h4>
         <img>
         <p>Text</p>
       </section>
       ....
       ....
      </footer>
    </body>
```

Since I don't want the weighting of the web page to be so high in the footer or even in the header, there should be no H2 there, but only h3 or h4. <- that I my basic understanding.

Unfortunately I do not have any good references for this.

But the "perfect" HTML5 structure is that I should keep the order of the headings.
Like:

```html
    <h1>
    <h2>
    <h2>
      <h3>
      <h3>
    <h2>
    <h2>
```

**The code is also okay for me in the content / main area.**
But not for the Footer, Header, Aside...

Some tools can measure the order.
Do I then have to do the following for the footer for example?

**Here a Footer markup example:**

```html
      ....
      </main>
      <footer>
       <h2 class="hidden">Footer</h2>
       <h3 class="hidden">Footer</h3>
       <section>
         <h4>Headline 1</h4>
         <img>
         <p>Text</p>
       </section>
       ....
       ....
      </footer>
    </body>
```

And now i can use a <h4 in the Footer... ?

**Another markup example:**
About a header slider there is no H1 or h2 over there, but all individual slides should get only one H3.

Like this:

```html
    <body>
      <header>
        <section>
          <h3>COMPANY NAME</h3>
          <nav>META NAVIGATION</nav>
        </section>
        <nav>MAINMENU</nav>
      </header>
      <main>
        <section>
          <div SLIDER>
            <div ITEM1>
              <h3>
              <p>
              <img> or BG-IMG
            </div>
            <div ITEM2>
              <h3>
              <p>
              <img> or BG-IMG
            </div>
            ...
          </div>
        </section>
        ....
```

i hope you can help me :) Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

The headline tags were designed to create an outline or table of contents of the page. When using Web Accessibility software the software and you select headlines the software will read the first headline ... the h1 tag ... then wait for a user response. At the user response to read or open the headlines under h1, it will read the h2 tags. If the user selects the h2 tag it will read the h3 tags under that h2 tag ... otherwise, the h3 tags are not read.

So the headline tags are navigation tools. People can choose to listen to the part of the page they are interested in or can return to that part of the page, ... Just like most people use a table of contents to find a page in a book ... instead of reading the whole page from the beginning. Orphan tags are skipped.

### From WIA https://www.w3.org/WAI/test-evaluate/preliminary/#headings

[image]

Reading the headlines on your "should page" reads as

```
<h1>Headline</h1>
   <h2>Headline 2</h2>
       <h3>Teaser Headline</h3>
   <h2>Headline</h2>
          <h4>Headline</h4>
          <h4>Headline 1</h4>
```

- So when I select h1 it reads "headline 2" and "headline"
- If I select headlines for "headline 2" it reads "teaser headline"
- If I select headlines for "headline" it reads "headline," "headline1"

I'm not certain without context but I believe both your h4 should be h2? and I believe your

```
<h3>COMPANY NAME</h3>
```

is an orphan that never gets read when navigating using headlines.

### Search Engines use CSS

If you are using the headline tags as size / weight tags that is not best practice. You can simply use a class name instead. For SEO just consider them a div and the importance of the material in them expands by how much real estate they use on the page. I'm fairly certain search engines are only considering them as div because every time they allow content producers to tell the search engine what is important it works out badly. Correction: Google My Business has worked out well for verifiable businesses.

```
<style>
/* note class selector is more specific and in use for 
best practice of headline tags in HTML
but for the page layout classes can be used */ 

h1, .h1 {}
h2, .h2 {}
h3, .h3 {}
h4, .h4 {}
</style>
...
<h1 class="h3">Company Name</h1>
   <h2 class="h1">Headline</h2>
      <h3 class="h3">Teaser Headline</h3>
   <h2 class="h2">Headline</h2> <!-- t3 section headline -->
   <h2 class="h4">Headline</h2> <!-- footer headline-->
```

or maybe? I'm not sure what the content is going to be?

```
<div class="h3">Company Name</div>
<h1 class="h1">Page title main headline</h1>
   <h2 class="h3">teaser or introduction headline</h2>
   <h2 class="h2">Headline</h2>
   <h2 class="h4">A Footer headline</h2>
```

The size of the font, placement, and How much whitespace around it, gives the bot the details of how important it is or how much weight it should put on that text.

### Not all sites are marking up HTML correctly.

It is a common practice to use the h1 tag for the company name, it reads fine. It is a common practice to overuse headline tags where they don't need to be used. But if one wants to look forward.

Many Government agencies and some businesses are required to use them correctly.

> https://www.ada.gov/resources/web-guidance/
>
> This guidance describes how state and local governments and businesses
> open to the public can make sure that their websites are accessible to
> people with disabilities as required by the Americans with
> Disabilities Act (ADA).

So when I say AIRA has Google as a friend. I'm also saying Google does not want to do anything that would make them not a friend. Google's interest as well as those who influence Google is the semantic tags are used correctly.

That said, I've seen not "search" penalty for incorrect usage.

Although one should note ...

Title III Sample Cases

- Rite Aid Corporation: The Department reached an agreement with Rite Aid Corporation to address accessibility barriers in Rite Aid’s COVID-19 Vaccine Registration Portal.
- Teachers Test Prep, Inc.: The Department reached an agreement with Teachers Test Prep, Inc., regarding complaints that the test prep company’s online video courses did not provide captions and were inaccessible to people who are deaf.
- HRB Digital and HRB Tax Group (H&R Block): The Department reached an agreement with H&R Block to address claims that the company failed to code its website so that individuals with disabilities could use assistive technology such as screen reader software, refreshable Braille displays, keyboard navigation, and captioning.
- Peapod: The Department reached an agreement with Peapod to address claims that its online grocery delivery services were not accessible to some individuals with disabilities.

Comment: Thanks for there very niche and big answert. for the <main>-part I agree with you 100%! i have a question like the footer, can i use more HTML5 Headline outlines ? i think we dont need a perfect headline structur. i think with the new part <footer> we can take a <h3 or a <h4

Comment: I've not seen or noticed headlines being used in the footer but it is not incorrect. If you want a headline in the footer for [page outline or AIRA] navigation then use it. Otherwise make it a div. FYI a div can be made a headline with <div role="heading" aria-level="1">;This is a main page heading</div>; ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/heading_role

Comment: Using a <h3> after a <h2> makes it a child of the <h2>... to be a peer of the <h2> it is an <h2>

Comment: Note on <footer> the normal usage is the footer remains the same for all pages on the site. Google notices this and discounts its content for on page SEO, so if that last Headline is important for on-page technical SEO it may be best if it is not in the footer ... but then again if it is on every page, Google is still going to discount it or reassign it as site wide theme not specific to this page.

Comment: `<h1 class="h3">...</h1>` is not proper syntax. The HTML/CSS relationship for text tags are handled the same way the `<body>` tag is handled. `CSS: h1 { color:black; } h2 { color:green; }` `HTML: <h1>Company Name</h1>`

Comment: @elbrant by making .h1, .h2 ... classes, one can use the class instead of the element name .... css: .h1 {color:red} .h2 {color:black} ... so <h2 class="h1">Red not black</h2> ... and format the page as the design wants while maintaining outline hierarchy. or CSS h1, .h1 {color:red} /* note class has more specificity than element */

Comment: @Wayne.... there is no logic for your argument. I understand that you want your page to read "semantically correct", but looping back and forth between the already provided `h1 { }, h2 { }` syntax to your forced `.h1 { }, .h2{ }` where `<h1 class=".h3">` is going to make your code unreadable for newbies.

If you want your page to recognize `<h2>` as `h2 {color: black:}`, then code it appropriately. If you want another  call of `<h2>` to produce red, then add a `h2.red {color:red}` class.  

Please, keep it simple so that it doesn't confuse less experienced readers.

Comment: @Wayne I tried to find something that might help me explain myself better. In the end, what I am trying to say is that:   the HTML heading tags are inherently CSS selectors. So HTML `<h1>` = CSS `h1 { }` and/or CSS `.h1 { }`. CSS allows you to be creative with your selector names, but it's probably best to avoid the names of HTML elements.

Comment: @elbrant I would agree it is best to use class names that are not element names. Using element names would create a moment of confusion for the person reading it to determine what the author wanted to accomplish. In this use case; it is a flag, yes something unusual is in the HTML code. Elements that are not H1 tags are being formatted as if they are H1 tags ... Generally my code is h1, .h1 {/* rules */} -I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @elbrant thank you for helping me to answer the question better. Yes without the h1, .h1 {} it would be interpreted as an error by the next person reading it ... which could even be myself?

Comment: @elbrant for simple pages I would rather read <h1 class="logo"> than <h1 class="h1"> and when both are used <h1> without a class can be used with the suggested css rules. It is in the example for "wait what are we doing," but in the wild the syntax of a .h1 {} may be found; I did not invent its usage; I only discovered it. It usage is as a heads ups.

Comment: @Wayne thanks. the question is, can i use in the footer a h3 ? And in the footer is not the perfect headline structur, like h2, h3, h4 ... Here is the structur starting with h3, h4

Comment: If the "headline" tag above the h3 (footer headline tag) is a peer (also an h3) then it will be read as a peer. If the "headline" above the footer (h3 tag) headline is an h2 then it will be read as a sub-section of the tag above the footer ... the headline structure is independent from the basic HTML structure ... the reader when asked for headlines removes all HTML but the headline h# tags like the example from WIA.

Comment: @Wayne CSS rules automatically declare <h1> (etc.) as a class to be used as h1 { }. Therefore it is confusing to see a stylesheet with both h1{} and .h1{} declarations. It's redundant. You can still declare <p class="h1"> in your HTML if you so desire, but  `h1, .h1 {}`  is like having the same class declared twice. It doesn't make sense to me, so I have to question it's validity, please cite a reference for your example.

Comment: @elbrant bootstrap does it for you the browser doesn't. Bootstrap also uses class="display-1" ... "display-x" to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Wayne When Bootstrap indicates that ".h1 - .h6 are available", I interpret that to "read" as "class h1 thru class h6" which would be written in CSS `h1{ }`, thru `h6{ }` respectively.   The "dot(.)" before h1 is merely indicating that it is a "class", the same way that a "# (hashtag)" indicates an "id". There is no `.h1{ }` in the CSS because it is already given with `h1 { }`. So.... listing `h1, .h1 { }` in your CSS is the equivalent of saying "class h1, or class h1". Is that less confusing for you?

Comment: @elbrant The code ... <style>h1 {color:red}</style><h2 class="h1">what color am i</h1> ... does not produce red text when bootstrap is not loaded ... bootstrap creates the redundant <style>.h1 {color:red}</style> via javascript. If you don't use bootstrap you can do the same thing be declaring the style as <style>h1, .h1, display-1 {color:red}</style><h2 class="h1">this text is red</h2> Bootstrap is just creating two additional CSS rules from the h1 element rule. 1st the .h1 class and 2nd the .display-1 class.

Comment: @elbrant my recommendation is to remain within the style guidelines of the team, if they are using bootstrap don't add a rule to css. If they are not using bootstrap add a rule ... if the team style is use class names as for self documentation use something like <style>h1, .logo, large-headline {} h2, .med-headline {} h3, .small-headline {}</style>

Comment: @Wayne I would be glad to take this into a private chat with you.  I just really don't think you understand what I am saying.